# keras model does not work when it is part of the class

Tags: python, keras

So I have a class

```
class Trainer:
    def __init__(self,episodes):
        self.factorModel()

    def factorModel(self):
        self.model = Sequential()
        self.model.add(Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(3,200,200),dim_ordering="th",strides=4))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2) ))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu') )
        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2) ))
        self.model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Flatten())
        self.model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
        self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])


    def do(self,state):
        self.model.predict(np.array(state))[0]
```

When I try to call `do` I got error like `ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_2/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.` The problem occurs when I try run do function as a thread when I use the same model and the same config but i do not run do function as a thread everything works fine

full error message

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "path", line 141, in do
     self.model.predict_classes(state)[0]
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 268, in predict_classes
    proba = self.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1456, in predict
    self._make_predict_function()
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 378, in _make_predict_function
    **kwargs)
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3009, in function
    **kwargs)
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3479, in function
    return GraphExecutionFunction(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, **kwargs)
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3142, in __init__
    with ops.control_dependencies([self.outputs[0]]):
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5426, in control_dependencies
    return get_default_graph().control_dependencies(control_inputs)
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4867, in control_dependencies
    c = self.as_graph_element(c)
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3796, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3875, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_2/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I tried the solution from this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850089/is-keras-thread-safe) so I try to call `self.model._make_predict_function()` after `self.factorModel()` but in result i got this error 
`InvalidArgumentError: Tensor conv2d_1_input:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph`

Ok I found this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54873681/keras-model-fails-to-predict-if-called-in-a-thread) so probably there is no way to make prediction in Thread

So I made some changes according to suggestions to the code so now it looks like this:

```
class Trainer:
    def __init__(self,episodes):
        self.factorModel()
        self.graph = tf.get_default_graph() 


    def factorModel(self):
        self.model = Sequential()
        self.model.add(Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(3,200,200),dim_ordering="th",strides=4))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2) ))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu') )
        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2) ))
        self.model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Flatten())
        self.model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
        self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])


    def do(self,state):
        with self.graph.as_default():
            self.model.predict(np.array(state))[0]
```

and as a result I got following error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "path/Desktop/marioQProject/new_class_trainer.py", line 151, in do
    self.model.predict_classes(state)[0]
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 268, in predict_classes
    proba = self.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1462, in predict
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 324, in predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "patha/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3292, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "path/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1458, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable conv2d_1/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/conv2d_1/bias/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
         [[{{node conv2d_1/Reshape/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

Comment: Please post your full error trace.

Comment: @VivekMehta if this is important  do function is called in thread

Comment: Inside `__init__`, try initialising `self.model = None` and then call `self.factorModel()`

Comment: @YOLO I tried this and unfortunately still the same problem

Comment: Do you still face the problem if you call it normally, not in a thread?

Comment: @YOLO I have to admit I don't checked this, so when I run this function not inside of thread everything works fine

Comment: Why are you running a process intensive task inside a thread ?

Comment: I have one thread that runs a game in background and the second one with Trainer class that make screenshot of the game (state) and make prediction

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is not really friendly with multithread but there's a workaround.

Do this

```py
class Trainer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.factorModel()
        self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()  # [1]

    def do(self, state):
        with self.graph.as_default():  # [2]
            return self.model.predict(np.array(state))[0]

    def factorModel(self):
        self.model = Sequential()
        self.model.add(Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(10, 10, 3), strides=4))
        self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

t = Trainer()
def fn():
    t.do(np.zeros((1, 10, 10, 3)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_one = threading.Thread(target=fn)
    thread_two = threading.Thread(target=fn)
    thread_one.start()
    thread_two.start()
```

BTW if you don't specifically need `channel first` ordering then I recommend you to use TF standard `channel last` instead. Weather you get images directly with opencv or convert Pillow images to ndarray using numpy you'll get `channel last` by default.

## Edit

Have you tried to make sure the model works before send to threading, like

```
class Trainer:
    def __init__(self, episodes, model, graph):
        self.graph = graph
        self.model = model


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(...))
.
.
.
# make sure it runs here
model.predict(np.zeros((1, 3, 200, 200)))
# if you don't need to train then try not compile first
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
trainer = Trainer(episodes, model, graph)
```

Also the callable model instead of Sequential, like

```
from keras import models, layers
inp = layers.Input((200, 200, 3))
x = layers.Conv2D(50, (3, 3), activation='relu',strides=4)(inp)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2) )(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu')(x)
.
.
.
x = layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)
model = models.Model(inp, x)
```

Comment: So I try your solution and got following error `FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable conv2d_1/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/conv2d_1/bias/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.` I guess it can be problem with my environment but idk

Comment: Could you add the new traceback and your code to main question, especially the former

Comment: everything is up to date

Comment: I assume that normal `model.predict` doesn't work either as your traceback is `self.model.predict_classes`. I added something I can think of.